# Hexdecimal to String Convert - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, hex, converters

I'm trying to convert hexadecimal to string using Ruby and it does not work with some Chinese characters. I am new to Ruby.

Current code is working fine with non-Chinese characters but now code needs to support Chinese characters. It converts HexDecimal to string using ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 encoder:

```
extractpayload = "e5b7b2e5ae8ce68890e38082e68891e4bbace5b086e59ca8e5aea1e6a0b8e5b9b6e7a1aee8aea4e8aea2e58d95e5908ee58f91e8b4a7efbc8ce5b9b6e7ab8be58db3e4bba5e79fade4bfa1e5bda2e5bc8fe9809ae79fa5e682a8e3808220e69fa5e79c8be8aea2e58d95e4bfa1e681afe68896e7aea1e79086e794b5e5ad90e58f91e7a5a8";

gettransformedfullpayload1 = [extractpayload].pack("H*").force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8");
```

repl.it link: 
https://repl.it/@bonsshah/Ruby-Hexdecimal-to-String-Conversion

Expected output:

```
已完成。我们将在审核并确认订单后发货，并立即以短信形式通知您。 查看订单信息或管理电子发票
```

Currently getting this wrong output:

```
å·²å®æãæä»¬å°å¨å®¡æ ¸å¹¶ç¡®è®¤è®¢åååè´§ï¼å¹¶ç«å³ä»¥ç­ä¿¡å½¢å¼éç¥æ¨ã æ¥çè®¢åä¿¡æ¯æç®¡ççµå­åç¥¨
```

Comment: The very first thing you do is to forcefully encode the string in a character set that *doesn't have Chinese characters*. Of course, they are destroyed after that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Could you provide solution by sharing working sample ?

Answer (score 3):

It's already hex-dumped UTF-8.

```
str = "e5b7b2e5ae8ce68890e38082e68891e4bbace5b086e59ca8e5aea1e6a0b8e5b9b6e7a1aee8aea4e8aea2e58d95e5908ee58f91e8b4a7efbc8ce5b9b6e7ab8be58db3e4bba5e79fade4bfa1e5bda2e5bc8fe9809ae79fa5e682a8e3808220e69fa5e79c8be8aea2e58d95e4bfa1e681afe68896e7aea1e79086e794b5e5ad90e58f91e7a5a8" => "e5b7b2e5ae8ce68890e38082e68891e4bbace5b086e59ca8e5aea1e6a0b8e5b9b6e7a1aee8aea4e8aea2e58d95e5908ee58f91e8b4a7efbc8ce5b9b6e7ab8be58db3e4bba5e79fade4bfa1e5bda2e5bc8fe9809ae79fa5e682a8e3808220e69fa5e79c8be8aea2e58d95e4bfa1e681afe68896e7aea1e79086e794b5e5ad90e58f91e7a5a8"
[str].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-8') => "已完成。我们将在审核并确认订单后发货，并立即以短信形式通知您。 查看订单信息或管理电子发票"
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, 
I have hexdecimal with combination of chinese characters and regular english characters - Try this  "4d442020020000000000000008000000ffffffff0000000011010000b80400004d514852463220200000000001000000414d5120514d5347514d433031202020e778e65c05381b2031302e3133302e34302e313131353538363238383237363500000000e5b7b2e5ae8ce68890e38082e68891e4bbace5b086e59ca8e5aea1e6a0b8e5b9b6e7a1aee8aea4e8aea2e58d95e5908ee58f91e8b4a7efbc8ce5b9b6e7ab8be58db3e4bba5e79fade4bfa1e5bda2e5bc8fe9809ae79fa5e682a8e3808220e69fa5e79c8be8aea2e58d95e4bfa1e681afe68896e7aea1e79086e794b5e5ad90e58f91e7a5a8"

Comment: @FShah That doesn't work with Aaron's code because the bytes aren't valid UTF-8. Do you know what the original encoding is?

Comment: That's some sort of binary message format. It contains your original message. You may need to use something like bindata to extract messages if you have more in that format: "MD  \u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0011\u0001\u0000\u0000\xB8\u0004\u0000\u0000MQHRF2  \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000AMQ QMSGQMC01   \xE7x\xE6\\\u00058\e 10.130.40.11155862882765\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000已完成。我们将在审核并确认订单后发货，并立即以短信形式通知您。 查看订单信息或管理电子发票"

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge - but MD \u0002\.... will not be correct output. How do I get correct output in this case ? Could you help me out by providing working sample of this message on online ruby editor link.